# How can I extract a multi-volume zip file using SharpZipLib in C#?

Tags: c#, zip, 7zip, sharpziplib

I have a single file, Setup1.cab, which is split up into Setup1.zip.001 and Setup1.zip.002 that I used 7zip to archive. Once those volumes reach their destination, I'd like to be able to use C# to extract that file from both archives into the same directory where they will reside. Is this something that SharpZipLib is capable of, or should I be using another tool?

Otherwise, is there a way to combine the two using C# (or another tool - I'm open!) into one zip file, THEN extract it using SharpZipLib?
Thanks!

EDIT: 7zip will not be installed on the destination machines. Also, I'm open to using a different method of archiving the original file; I just need it to be in chunks of under 500MB, and the original file is 570MB.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at [the SevenZipSharp library](http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/) and actually use 7zip via C# to handle the decompression.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that 7zip will not be installed on the destination machine where I will need to extract. Is it safe to assume that a 7zip installation is required for that library to work?

Comment: @MyOtherCarlsEpona - You do need a copy of the 7zip binary. I'm not sure what the 7zip license says about it...but you could always simply bundle the binary with your application (and not require that the user actually install 7zip).